# How to convert a Object String to Object Guid in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DetailsView, I need get the value specifield in DataKeyNames "UserId" (a Guid Field) and add it to an Object Guid.

At the moment I am using this code:

```
String myUserId = (String)uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"].ToString();
```

but I would need something like:

```
Guid myUserGuid = (Guid)uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"].ToString();
```

But does not work I get error Error

```
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Guid'
```

What could be the problem? Thanks guys for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under debug: what object is uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"]
I guess this must be already the Guid; and conversion is not needed

Answer (score 6):

Well, the problem is that you're calling `ToString()` and then trying to cast that string to a `Guid`, when there's no such conversion available. Possible alternatives:

- Cast *instead* of calling `ToString()`, if the original value is really a Guid:

  ```
  Guid guid = (Guid)uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"];
  ```
- Parse the string instead:

  ```
  Guid guid = new Guid(uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"].ToString());
  ```

If this is user-entered data at all, or there's any other reason why the value is half-expected to be incorrect, and if you're using .NET 4, you might want to use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) instead, which will allow you to handle failure without an exception.

Comment: Thanks Jon it is working great the Cast version! Once again thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var myUserGuid = new Guid(uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"] stores a valid Guid

try this

```
Guid myUserGuid = (Guid)uxAuthorListDetailsView.DataKey["UserId"]
```

remove ToString method